# Special value of generalized Laguerre polynomials or of their quotient

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)$ denote a [generalized Laguerre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials). I would like to have a closed form for the expression
$$\frac{L_n^{(\alpha)}(1)}{L_{n-1}^{(\alpha)}(1)};$$
where we set $x=1$ and both $n$ and $\alpha$ are positive integers.

I'm aware, as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859290/quotient-of-confluent-hypergeometric-functions-of-the-1st-kind) on Math.SE, that the quotient can be expressed as a continued fraction. But this holds for any $x$, and I was hoping to get a closed form in my case, given its specificity. Mathematica doesn't seem to be of any help.

I would be grateful for any comment or idea.

Comment: Even when $\alpha=1$, the ratio you seek has no closed formula. In fact, $L_n(1)$ can be given as a binomial sum but lacks a closed form expression. I'm not sure what you were hoping for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I wasn't aware that already $L_n(1)$ lacks a closed form expression. Given $L_0^{(\alpha)}(1) = 0$, $L_1^{(\alpha)}(1) = \alpha$ and the recurrence relation
$$\frac{L_{k+1}^{(\alpha)}(1)}{L_{k}^{(\alpha)}(1)} = \frac{2k+\alpha}{k+1} -\frac{k+\alpha}{k+1}\frac{L_{k-1}^{(\alpha)}(1)}{L_{k}^{(\alpha)}(1)} ,$$
I was hoping that an explicit solution could be given. (I mean, it is clear that this recurrence relation is solved by Laguerre polynomials, but the hope is that something easier could come up!)